# Complex alternative question with OR, do I need the verb before the subject twice?

Tags: grammar, questions, complex-sentences

Which is correct?

> Would you like to have such feature or it is unnecessary?

or

> Would you like to have such feature or is it unnecessary?

Comment: Would you consider "Is it a dog or it is a wolf?" acceptable?

Comment: The second version ("is it" vs "it is") is much more idiomatic.

Comment: @HotLicks thanks for the comments guys, this question was for google as well, I couldn't find any info. So it is correct to make few questions in one sentence? I thought you use "question grammar" only once at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in terms of grammar, the second sentence would be correct, because it contains two questions that can be appropriately punctuated with a single question mark at the end.

The first sentence, however, contains both a question and a declarative sentence ("it is unnecessary"). The question mark would then be appropriate only for the question.